# Visual Studio not generating WebForms Designer Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, msbuild

We've got a bunch of legacy WebForms projects that we've just upgraded to use SDK style `.csproj` files so at least that matches what we've got everywhere else until we can migrate away from WebForms (also makes some binding redirect nightmares go away).

Now, if I'm using Rider, and I edit an `.aspx` file, it correctly updates the `.designer.cs` file.

However, if I'm using Visual Studio, it no longer updates the `.designer.cs` file.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

---

In terms of what I've looked at so far, I'm going to assume that Rider is calling something in the background to do that code generation. So presumably, if VS won't do that for SDK projects, we could add that manually as a pre-build action, I'm just having a hard time working out exactly what's being called to do this.

---

So an example:

The project is called `ClientInterface` and we'll use the `ErrorPage.aspx` which is in the root of that project.

The `.aspx` file (with most of the content removed) looks like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableSessionState="False" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ErrorPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClientInterface.ErrorPage" %>
<%@Register tagPrefix="css" tagName="ClientInterface" src="ClientInterfaceCss.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body id="NewStylesPageBody" class="ErrorScreen">
    <form id="form" runat="server">
        <div class="GreenGradientScreen">
            <div class="ErrorBox">
                <div class="ErrorHeaderBox">
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image" ImageUrl="~/Images/Controls/header-bar-logo.png?new-logo" />
                    <asp:Image runat="server" ID="ErrorIcon" ImageUrl="~/Images/red-error.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `CodeBehind`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace ClientInterface
{
    public partial class ErrorPage : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And the file properties on the `CodeBehind` look like: [image: codebehind properties]

Comment: You are troubling yourself, as nobody is there to support you on that path. Microsoft does not make the SDK style applicable for legacy projects. You might get some hints from projects like https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb, but again only the author(s) can guide you further.

Comment: It's a workaround rather than a solution, which is why I haven't posted it, but this R# plugin adds a button in the gutter to invoke the JetBrains designer compilation https://github.com/ulrichb/Roflcopter I imagine this is the same thing as Rider is doing behind the scenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the best solution in the world but it does work and it's what we've gone with.

If you have Resharper installed (at this point, who doesn't) you can use the [Roflcopter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11757-roflcopter) plugin.

This has some functionality that calls into the Jetbrains implementation of the designer file generation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how you converted this from a web site to a web site applicaiton.

In most cases, you find that you MUST change the page directive from:

```
 CodeFile = "yourwebpage.cs"
```

to

```
 CodeBehind = "yourwebpage.cs"
```

Also, make sure the inrertis directive also includes the application name space.

So, in above, I am say in a folder (from root) in test 4.

so, then this:

```
CodeBehind="MyPbarTest.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="CSharpWebApp.Test4.MyPbarTest"
```

Note the codeBehind does not have any path name, or name space.
But, the Inherites will have:

```
  CSharWebApp   - the application namespace
  .test4   - the folder
  .MyParTest  - the page name without .cs and without .aspx
```

So, above is for a page called MyParTest.aspx

thus, I'll have this (the 3 files).

[image]

So, converting from web site means that each page directive should be changed from CodeFile to CodeBehind.

also, ensure that the .cs file has a build action in property sheet like this:

[image]

At this point, if you modify the aspx file, and save (ctr-s), then the designer file should be updated.

so, for web sites you see "codefile", and that is incorrect for a web site application.

Comment: So I've added the `.aspx` and properties to my question, I think we're already doing everything you've said, but I could be wrong

Comment: I would as a quick test add a new web page from vs - say mytest.aspx. I would take a look at the top most page directive and see what it creates. If that is ok, then we assume you opening this project as a project, and not using file->open web site then, right?

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't work mate, I've tried your suggestion

Comment: and you are opening this as a project - NOT using file-open web site? Create a new blank page (of course using vs to create/add the test page. Say  mytest (mytest.aspx), and see if that page works.